# Eclipse: Tons of Errors in Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I imported my current Android Project to Eclipse on my (Mac OS) device via SVN.
The code shows up alright, but Ecipse shows tons of errors (see screenshot) which do not appear on the device I first used - I am not very experienced with Eclipse but I guess some libraries were not imported?
I installed the current JRE(1.7), Eclipse, the Android plugin which also installed the current Android SDK (4.1).
Any clues?!

[image: The error Shows like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the sdk path in **Window->Preference->android**.

[image]
And then Click apply.
If you already do it. Then right click the project and goto **Properties->android->select android version**

Comment: Are you add sdk path to eclipse

Answer (score 0):

1. **Right click on Project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties**
2. Go to **menu -> Project -> Clean**

For that go to each java file import all required packages or try `CTRL + SHIFT + O`

then resolve all errors in `RES` folder.

Then it will generate `R.java` for you

then `import yourpakagename.R;` where ever required.

remove `import android.R;`

hope this will help you

Comment: it just deleted all my android imports - the errors are still there